# Delete record from firebase without ID

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have inserted data and displaying it in List view as I am new to Firebase i dont know how to delete it.

My data format:
[image]

Code that i have tried to delete is:

```
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            member.setName(list.get(position));
        }
    });
   btnDelete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
           public void onClick(View v) {
           final String str = member.getName().substring(0,24);
           if (str == "") {
               Toast.makeText(Retreivedata.this, "plz select record to delete", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
           }else {

           ref.child("Member").child(str).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
               @Override
               public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                   ref.child(str).removeValue();
               }

               @Override
               public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

               }
           });
           Toast.makeText(Retreivedata.this,"Record is deleted",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
               Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Retreivedata.class);
               startActivity(intent);
           }
           }
```

Suggest me what to set onclick of delete button.!!

Answer (score 1):

**I would suggest using `firebase recycler adapter` or `android recycler view` to load your data, but for your case this is what you can do:**

**Not the best way, but lets say you want to delete an item `on click`, and assuming that all `names` are different:**

I assumed that `member.getName()` is giving you the name of the clicked item:

```
btnDelete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
 @Override
 public void onClick(View v) {


//ref
DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Member");

//Query
Query query = ref.orderByChild("name").equalTo(member.getName());


ValueEventListener listener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){

         //remove
         ds.getRef().removeValue();

       }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
};
query.addValueEventListener(listener);


}
});
```